# Package a python script with libraries

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, package

I'm trying to bundle together a python script in Ubuntu 16 such that it will be able to run as a standalone program on Windows. I am ok with bringing with it any folders I have to, as long as I don't have to install anything on the Windows side. I know the easiest thing would be to include all the packages together in one folder. However, some packages like `numpy` and `pygame` are installed directly in my machine, so I would have to hunt down stand-alone folders and individually test to make sure they work with the python script.

I know there are applications out there that attempts to compress a python script to an executable. I have already tried `pyinstaller`, `py2exe` and `py2app`. Every one of these assumes that the only modules I am using are installed packages like numpy and pygame listed above. However, I am also using the module [SGC](http://www.pygame.org/project-SGC-2089-4505.html), which is not a normal python module but one I installed manually (For the record, AFAIK it can only be installed by running the `build.py` and `install.py` script in the SGC folder). I've tried making an executable and running it with SGC in the same folder, but that doesn't work.

Pyinstaller was able to use both SGC and the regular modules. However, its executable was only able to work on Linux, not Windows. So after using this [very buggy script](https://github.com/paulfurley/python-windows-packager) to use Pyinstaller on wine, I came to find that, once again, it assumes I'm only using regular modules and doesn't give any idea how to include SGC.

I know this question is a little vague, but surely in the vast world of python there is some straight-forward way of distributing my python script from one machine to another, right?

I know I could install Python on the windows side and start from scratch again, but surely there has to be a better option.

Comment: Have you looked at pypi?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi

Comment: The 'very buggy script' you're using will setup a windows python environment. You need to install SGC in that environment and then you should be able to build your app. It may be non-trivial to install SGC.

Comment: @Eric I am aware of that, that is why I stopped using that, as I explained in the question. I have no idea if it is even possible to install SGC in the windows python environment, let alone how trivial it is

Comment: If you don't have access to a physical windows system to build and test your package, can you use a virtual machine?  If not and if customising the python-windows-packager is too difficult as you mention, then perhaps [this article on setting up wine](https://andreafortuna.org/technology/how-to-cross-compile-a-python-script-into-a-windows-executable-on-linux/) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Eric's suggested article, but with some tweaks for my task.

`wine pyinstaller` is able to find modules for python two different ways: 1) if the module is located in the current directory or 2) if the module is installed specifically on wine (not Ubuntu).

Because I have the SGC folder, I was able to run `wine pyinstaller` in the same directory, thus solving that issue. As for each of the other modules, I installed them in wine using the following commands:

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Python27/
wine python.exe Scripts/pip.exe install pygame
wine python.exe Scripts/pip.exe install numpy
```

Then I was able to create the executable for windows this way:

```
cd ~/Documents/folder_with_sgc/
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Python27/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe --onefile Loop.py
```

And verified it worked this way:

```
cd dist/
wine Loop.exe
```